# Rewriting to my index.html not working with the local IIS

Tags: iis, web-applications, azure-static-web-app

I have installed on my local machine (with the IP address 192.168.0.19) the IIS. I setup the site binding on IIS to HTTPS port 443

My configuration web.config file located in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scheduler` - my website app is called scheduler and looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Force Index.html" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect index.html" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="index.html/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Long story short I thought that if I specify anything in the url that starts with https://192.168.0.19 would redirect to index.html of my web application `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scheduler`. But is does not. It displays always error `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`.
Can someone help with setting up this rewriting stuff please.

My current web.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect to scheduler" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^192.168.0.19$" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/scheduler/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Use privacy tabs of a browser for all your testing. 2. Enable FRT to learn more about the errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: 1) What are privacy tabs?

Comment: Lex Li                                                                                                                                          1) I have installed URL `Rewrite Module 2.1`                                                                               2) I can't see Enabling FRT under the `Actions/Configure`

Comment: OK. I figured out privacy tabs are incognito windows -  i didn't know about that                  I have found out how to enable the FRT but when I try to open in browser `http://localhost/article.aspx` I get `HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found`. The file article.aspx is definitely in C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make sure that there is site in iis with the binding exist. if not you could try to add the site bindings with this specific ip address.

Then add the below rule to that site:

```
 <rule name="redirect to scheduler" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^192.168.0.19$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/scheduler/index.html" />
            </rule>
```

update:

after i have checked your site and folder structure I found  that you are using the site root folder to the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ but the web.config and the rule is added to the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scheduler folder that is the reason rule is not working. i would like to suggest you to move the url rewrite rule to the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ path

Comment: Jalpa Panchal The site in IIS with the binding does exist - it is set to HTTPS port 443                                    I Tried both urls (url="/scheduler/index.html" and url="/index.html") - no luck so far still experimenting

Comment: @Janciu may i know what is the current result and where did you added the url rewrite rule?

Comment: I added the rewrite rule to my current `web.config` - you can see it in my original question above (I added it to the end of my question). I added `web.config` to the folder  `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scheduler`. I am currently getting an error `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`.

Comment: @Janciu could you share your iis site binding and folder structure detail? does /scheduler/index.html exist in the folder ? i would like to suggest to add this url rewrite rule with site where you have site bindings with ip 192.168.0.19 configured

Comment: I added public repository on github [Scheduler](https://github.com/rejkid/SharedScheduler)

Comment: @
Jalpa Panchal
 Thanks for helping me. I really appreciate it. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Janciu could you share the iis site binding snapshot

Comment: It's added to my original post - at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255222/discussion-between-janciu-and-jalpa-panchal).